# "Cannot find module 'fs'" after importing Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, fs

I'm building a Angular4-App with Electron. I used the following project as a template:
https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron

I always used fs in one of my services, and so far it worked perfectly. I imported it like this:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Now I wanted to also use Angular Material. I followed this guide:
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

After completing it, npm start fails with this error:

```
ERROR in C:/projects/angular2/angular-electron/src/app/providers/XmlLoader.service.ts (2,21): Cannot find module 'fs'.
```

I already tried reverting all imports I made by hand for Material.
I also reimported the node typings, as was suggested in another thread.

Edit: I found a solution, though I'm not sure why it works.
I restored "electron.service.ts", and now everything is working, even though I deleted all references and imports to the service (even imports in the app.module).